# Swapping a List

Tags: python, swap

I'm stuck on this one because I've never used swap before. I've tried a few different ways but keep getting an error that swap is not defined.

Write a function swap that swaps the first and last elements of a list argument.

Sample output with input: 'all,good,things,must,end,here'
['here', 'good', 'things', 'must', 'end', 'all']

```
values_list = input().split(',')  # Program receives comma-separated values like 5,4,12,19
swap(values_list)

print(values_list)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: python. sorry i am new here. my professor linked this site for any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```py
def swap(alist):
    alist[0], alist[-1] = alist[-1], alist[0]
    return 

values_list = input().split(',')  # Program receives comma-separated values like 5,4,12,19
swap(values_list)

print(values_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your swap function look like? All you would have to do would be to create a temp variable and assign the first element to it, then assign the last element to the first element, and then the temp to the last element to do this.